# use Django with two Vuejs components project

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

so i have a project that i created with vuejs and django, for authentication i did it with session authentification. so when it connects it launches vue js project but i wanted to know can i do it when it won't be authentify like do i create a new vuejs project or i can use the old one. or tell me if you have a other proposition .
ps: i know that there are Jwt Authentification]

```
#python url to lunch vuejs 
re_path(r"^(?!media/).*$", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point"),
```

**the view :**

```
class IndexTemplateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        if not settings.DEBUG:
            template_name = "index.html"
        else:
            template_name = "index-dev.html"
        return template_name
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use SessionAuthentication**

From django-rest-framework's official docs [SessionAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) is appropriate for AJAX clients that are running in the same session context as your website.

**Use TokenAuthentication**

Consider using [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) which is appropriate for client-server setups, your vue.js app being the client